# Repeat last command with an exclamation? Vim

Tags: vim

When I've just typed a huge command such as:

```
:e ~/Projects/foo/app/views/bar.rhtml
```

Vim inevitably tells me that I haven't saved the current buffer. Is there a quick way to repeat the command with an exclamation point, without having to retype the whole thing?

Comment: Not related to question, but I wonder (from a Windows person): Why do people use vim? When one has to type commands for every small thing like saving a file when it can be done with keyboard shortcuts like ctrl+s ? I use gVim now and then, but the only good use I get from it is that I can edit files without extensions easily.

Comment: Zabba - see here: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/

Comment: @Zabba: Commands and keyboard shortcuts are the same thing.  You can even bind ("map") ctrl-s to saving the current file in gvim, if that's what you want.  Also useful: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/29/everyone-who-tried-to-convince-me-to-use-vim-was-wrong/

Comment: Take a look at `:set hidden` and `:help 'hidden'`.

Comment: @Zabba: One reason vim rocks is because of the : escape to "line mode" that was originally designed and written by Ken Thompson himself, then carried forward to vi(1) and vim(1). 35 years later, there is still no better way to transform a file than with :g and :s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:e! #
```

When specifying vim files, `%` is a shortcut to the current file and `#` is a shortcut to the "previous" (really, more like "other") file, which in your case is `~/.../bar.rhtml`

Answer (score 3):

`q:` will bring up the history and you can edit the commands directly and then hit enter to run them again, or you can do as zigdon suggested and `:<up><home><right>!`

Answer (score 2):

`:<up><home><right>!`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know offhand is to hit `ESC :` and then use history (either `^p` or up-arrow) to get at your previous command again.  Ironically editing within that buffer is more emacs-like than vi-like.

You could actually bind this to a key with `:map ! :^[OA^[[1~^[OC!^M` (each of those escape characters and the ^M need to be actual escape characters -- you can get them by typing `^V` first)

Comment: Why not `map ! :<up><home><c-right>!<cr>`? No need for ^V and much easier to edit in .vimrc.